# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: si.gov.fu.InvoiceRequest - how to resolve?

Tags: java

I get this error when I try to run my code, project builds normally, also I get no errors while compiling and packaging everything into .jar file. I am using Intellij software.

eveything stops when I try to call this line:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InvoiceRequest.class);
```

I have imported the:
    import si.gov.fu.*;
    import si.gov.fu.InvoiceRequest;

But at first, when I tried to import second library, I had the InvoiceRequest crossed, like I cannot use it, even though it has been compiled and packed up like it should.

Any clue?

Best regards

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a jar file (or class within the jar) when you're running the code. If `si.gov.fu.InvoiceRequest` is in a different jar file, you need both your jar file *and* that jar file to be on the classpath. (Unless you're specifically trying to package everything into a single jar file.)

Comment: Yes, but other classes from si.go.fu.* , which are inside, are implemented normally? How the heck that only one class is missing?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "implemented normally" I'm afraid - and we don't really have enough context to know what's going on. Please provide more information, or it'll be really hard to help you. Basically you need to make sure that all the relevant classes are available at execution time. It could be that you're using an old version of the library at execution time which contains some but not all of the classes, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a runtime error. Guess your program was compiled and linked successfully, but the `InvoiceRequest` is not available at runtime, that is it is changed since compilation.

InvoiceRequest is in the classpath, otherwise you would have got a ClassNotFoundException, the `NoClassDefFoundError` is a runtime error.

So recompile and deploy again with the dependencies in proper order.